# Can not fire a event from a Polymer 3 Mixin

Tags: polymer, dom-events, polymer-3.x

I have the below in a mixin. However, `dispatchEvent` is not attached to `this`. I get the error `Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined`.

So, I used `window.dispatchEvent`  instead but the event doesn't get caught by the parent element. Any ideas what I can do to fire a event in a mixin?

```
  fetchError(response) {
      ...
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
        'http-error', {bubbles: true, detail: msg, composed: true}
      ));
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
```

Comment: Can't produce this error with above info. I just made a demo for another question for `this.thispatchEvent` at this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cant-able-to-bind-value-from-the-json-through-object-referen?file=index.js  . Beside I just wonder msg has no value! usage is `msg:"someValue"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to bind the method

Add this to your mixin:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.fetchError = this.fetchError.bind(this)
}
```